# Empty result when geocoding address in Sweden using MMQGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, geocoding, mmqgis, sweden

I am trying to geocode an address in QGIS. I am aware of the MMQGIS Plugin and I have been trying to use that.

The dialogue window appears as though it is catered to US addresses as it contains a column for `"State"`. The address that I want to geocode is Swedish. The CSV file in which I have the address is formatted in *UTF-8*. I also have the Google API Key.

When the geocoding is done a new layer is added in the panel but it doesn't contain any information and nothing appears on the map. You can see some screenshots below.

A CSV file:
[image]

My empty result after Geocoding:
[image]

Comment: Well, it appears that script is the way to go. I have no knowledge of script unfortunately.

Comment: I did try using OSM but it produced a point in France instead of Sweden. I thought i had to do with wrong CRS but when I changed it the point appeared in the Atlantic ocean instead. Same result with replacing ä, ö, å with Latin equivalents.

Comment: Free of charge.. Hm.. what an immature attitude towards helping someone. If you are willing to help for free then do not charge your assistance with so much malice. The Google alternative doesn't work. Must be something wrong with my API-key. Thanks for the free example. –

Comment: Sorry I meant that Google (since you have an api key) quality is probably much better than OSM...I don’t have access to Google, so I could help only with OSM Data. Sorry for confusing!

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's kind of you. But there actually is no data. Initially I needed to see if geocoding would be possible at all before I actually proceeded with collecting data. So I just tested the geocoding functions in QGIS using the address I provided in the original post above.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

This is a limitation of the plugin. It accepts ASCII characters only. Try changing special characters by it's nearest ASCII equivalent: ä by a etc. Otherwise, use another Geocoding method.

See here for details:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382550/88814

Comment: I tried it. It gives me coordinates and creates a point-layer but it ends up in France...  and the attribute table shows some other address (at least the same city though) than the one I imported.

Comment: Ok, so try ANSI: @Taras solution. If that doesn't work, either, I guess you have to use another method. As stated: encoding of special characters is a limitation of the plugin

Comment: I did. Se my response to his/her suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds silly but *if you work on Windows* you may try using *the ANSI encoding* (I know that *UTF-8* should be used), see the image below

[image: result]

For more details, please check [What is ANSI format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format).

---

As @Babel suggested, I also tried using *ANSI encoding* with other addresses that possess Latin and special Latin characters. They were successfully geocoded with MMQGIS, please see the image below.

[image: result2]

Unfortunately, it did not work with non-Latin characters.

They can be encoded in UTF-8, viewed in Notepad++ but not geocoded in MMQGIS.
[image: no_result_utf]

They could not be encoded in ANSI, some details were described in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65695389/encoding-from-ansi-when-having-non-latin-letters#comment116159581_65695389).
[image: no_result_ansi]

---

**References:**

- [ANSI character set and equivalent Unicode and HTML characters](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html)
- [ASCII and ANSI Character Table](https://www.gaijin.at/en/infos/ascii-ansi-character-table)
- [wikipedia | ANSI character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_character_set)

Comment: Thanks, @Taras - to be sure: **saving** non-latin characters correctly is possible with UTF-8, but not with ANSI (your screenshots), but **geocoding** with MMQGIS fails in both cases, right? So to say: The plugin works 1. With UTF-8: ASCII only, 2. With ANSI: ASCII plus special characters of the latin alphabet 3. With either encoding for non-latin alphabets - is that correct? So for non-latin scripts, at the moment there seems to be no way to geocode them with MMQGIS, correct?

Comment: 1. Plugin works with ANSI only when they are Latin and special Latin characters. 2. Non-Latin can not be encoded in ANSI. Other cases were not investigated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the OSM-Geocoding? Otherwise the fault is likely to be in the Formatting of the CSV.