# MMQGIS Geocoder: Japanese addresses not being geocoded

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, geojson, geocoding, mmqgis

I have a handful of Japanese addresses, and not one of them are being geocoded in the latest version of QGIS (v. 3.22). It's probably because I'm not typing them in correctly. That being said, how does one type a Japanese address properly to get a match?

Example addresses: are any of these correct?

1. Hankyu-Higashi bldg.2F,Doyama-Cho,Kita-Ku, Osaka
2. Japan, 〒530-0027 Osaka, Kita Ward, Doyamacho, 4−4 阪急東ビル 2F
3. 西荻南3-14-10 Suginami-ku, Tokyo, Japan 167-0053
4. 4-36-6 Ryougoku Sumida-ku Toukyou-to

I'm using the MMQGIS plugin, and the OpenStreetMap webservice. I'm not interested in the Google webservice. I also do not have a street file. In my *.csv table of addresses I have fields for the address, city and country. My other addresses in Europe and the US geolocated just fine.

[image]

I then tried the addresses in the search on the OpenStreetMap page, but they were not found there either.

Comment: Try using the native ["Batch Nominatim geocoder"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#batch-nominatim-geocoder) tool instead of MMQGIS plugin. Otherwise, you may have to switch to a provided with richer address data

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382550/88814

Comment: I tried the native geocoder. The results were the same. It did not find a single address. Thanks for the tips. I'll report back after some more digging.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to geocode your addresses using several geocoders (arcgis, bing, google, here, nominatim), and was able to get several results:

| address \ geocoder | arcgis | bing | google | here | nominatim |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hankyu-Higashi bldg.2F,Doyama-Cho,Kita-Ku, Osaka | (34.70347, 135.503196) | (34.702831, 135.503006) | (34.703526, 135.503393) | None | None |
| Japan, 〒530-0027 Osaka, Kita Ward, Doyamacho, 4−4 阪急東ビル 2F | (34.702369, 135.502403) | (34.702366, 135.502396) | (34.702339, 135.502399) | None | None |
| 西荻南3-14-10 Suginami-ku, Tokyo, Japan 167-0053 | (35.703612, 139.600975) | (35.700428, 139.602783) | (35.6996, 139.60314) | (35.68881, 139.65872) | None |
| 4-36-6 Ryougoku Sumida-ku Toukyou-to | (35.695144, 139.795666) | (35.693623, 139.794052) | (35.693775, 139.792689) | (35.74279, 139.81407) | None |

Maybe try choosing a different geocoder in the MMQGIS plugin.

Comment: I know for a fact they all can be found on Google Maps as that has been my main reference to find these places. However, I'm sticking to OSM mainly because I'm using it as the basemap for my JS app--and I want to keep addresses in consistent format, if that makes any sense.

Comment: I've managed to get them all geocoded with QGIS's native geocoder. I'll post some proof shortly.

Comment: I am happy for you, I would like to see your solution ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get all the addresses geocoded with the native "Batch Nomination geocoder" as pointed out in the comments and used in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141878/geocoding-addresses-to-coordinates-in-qgis/416022#416022). Here's how the addresses look in the *.csv file. **Note:** 1. and 2. in my original question were two attempts at the same location

1. Rock Stakk Records
2. Rock Stakk Records
3. 西荻シルクロード Nishiogi-kita 3-chome Suginami Tokyo 167-0053 Japan
4. Keiyo Road Ryogoku 3-chome Sumida Tokyo 130-0026 Japan

"Rock Stakk Records" worked as an address only because I added the feature directly in [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org/). It wasn't a feature before this. Now you can search that place by its name alone (same goes for other locations you give the name to). OSM also gave me the address of it after the edit, but without the leading "Rock Stakk Records" in the address it finds nothing, curiously. Additionally, I noticed you can use commas when you put the addresses in parenthesis. So, three of the following four inputs also work.

1. "Rock Stakk Records, Building 2F, Ogimachi-dori, Doyamacho, Kita Ward, Osaka, Osaka Prefecture, 530-0027, Japan"
2. "Building 2F, Ogimachi-dori, Doyamacho, Kita Ward, Osaka, Osaka Prefecture, 530-0027, Japan" **--No Results**
3. "Pit Bar, 西荻シルクロード, Nishiogi-kita 3-chome, Suginami, Tokyo, 167-0053 Japan"
4. "Ryōgoku Sunrize, Keiyo Road, Ryogoku 3-chome, Sumida, Tokyo, 130-0026, Japan"